# PowerShell command to get list of documents where users x and y has permissions?

Tags: permissions, powershell, object-model

I would like to get a list of documents where user x and y has permissions. Can someone help me? I would like to do it in either PowerShell or C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SPList.DoesUserHavePermission() method on lists.

```
foreach (var list in web.Lists)
{
    SPFieldUserValue flduserVal = new SPFieldUserValue(web, "1#;Administrator");
    SPUser user = flduserVal.User;
    bool hasPermissions = web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems);
    //some code
}
```

More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx).